# how do I get most recent 10 calls in group concat with a query?

Tags: mysql

Here is my table structure

```
phone_calls(id, phone_number, call_id, timestamp, colx, col y )
```

I want to retrieve 10 most recent calls from `phone_calls` table within a group concat, **without sub query**

Answer (score 2):

Try this (without a subquery it will not work):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(call_id)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        call_id 
    FROM 
        phone_calls 
    ORDER BY 
        id DESC 
    LIMIT 10
) as tmp
```

**UPDATE:** without sub-query:

```
SET @c:='';
SELECT 
    @c:=CONCAT(@c,',',call_id) 
FROM 
    phone_calls 
ORDER BY 
    id DESC 
LIMIT 10;
SELECT @c;
```

Comment: it returns all calls made by him

Comment: so you want the hole row returned?

Comment: I want 10 most recent calls using group_concat in one column and that too without sub query

Comment: @Stephan OP looking for a solution without a sub query

Comment: @TNK thx ,i saw that, im trying to figure out how it can be done

Comment: @Chella pls try the second query

Comment: @Stepahn: Thanks a lot, but Why I insisted on without subquery is, this is a small part of a Query which is operating on about million records, I dont want to make it slower any more than this. So I asked for such solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Chella np , even using a sub query should be fast since you have limit 10... you can do a benchmark and compare both solutions

Comment: my requirement is like a bit tricky, I need to fetch the records from 3 tables, in which in a table the corresponding value will be in the nearest record(not in the same record/row) along with some other data. I need to find it out(I found), and I need to extract it(extracted it).But now got this kind of problem. now tell me is this a good solution to write a subquery again inside of it. so I asked a query without subquery. just FYI. Thanks

Comment: as i said before test both ways an compare the times also use `SQL_NO_CACHE` so that the results can be worth something

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not sure if this is your problem, but to use group_concat you need a group by column right? Not sure if this will work but you can try it, I used this dummy col way before

```
select 1 as col, group_concat(call_id) as latest_calls from phone_calls
ORDER BY timestamp DESC GROUP BY col LIMIT 10
```

you'll have an extra useless column col, but latest_calls should be correct

Comment: nope..! it returns all calls buddy..! we can do it through a sub query , but I dont want it